# How to find my database ConnectionString in mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm setting up a setting.properties in my project where i can access my mySQL workbench database from my project and grab some datas.

Where do i find my connection String in the program?

Answer (score 4):

On the Home screen of MySQL Workbench, right click on the desired MySQL Connection and you will see an option to 'Copy  Connection string to Clipboard',
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no connection string in MySQL Workbench. I assume you mean one that can be used e.g. via ODBC or Java?

Instead you have to create it yourself with the credentials you used to connect in Workbench, plus any additional info.